# .NET - Custom Events

Tags: .net

The following code was taken from the ASP.NET page class (using Reflector):

```
Public Custom Event InitComplete As EventHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            MyBase.Events.AddHandler(Page.EventInitComplete, value)
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            MyBase.Events.RemoveHandler(Page.EventInitComplete, value)
        End RemoveHandler
    End Event
```

Why is there no RAISE EVENT? The following article suggests there should be a RAISE EVENT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184583%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.  I would expect to see:

```
Public Custom Event InitComplete As EventHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            MyBase.Events.AddHandler(Page.EventInitComplete, value)
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            MyBase.Events.RemoveHandler(Page.EventInitComplete, value)
        End RemoveHandler
        Raise Event
        End Raise Event
    End Event
```

I realise this is probably a basic question, but I am new to custom events and it is proving to be more difficult than I anticipated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my answer to your previous question: this indicates that `Page` wasn't written in VB.

.NET events don't have to have "raise" accessors. C# doesn't even have any syntax to let you *specify* a raise accessor.

VB, however, *does* make it a requirement of custom events. That's fine - any code generated from VB with a custom event will have a raise accessor. VB can't force its requirements onto other languages though - so any code which has an event without a raise access has no direct equivalent in VB.

Leave events out of things for a minute - suppose someone invented a new language called Humbug, which compiled to IL. It would be feasible for Humbug to specify that properties *had* to always have a getter and a setter. You couldn't write a property with only a getter or only a setter. It's fine for that to target IL, although the language would have to interoperate with code which only specified one part of a property. Any code in VB or C# which had a read-only (or write-only, though that's rare) event would simply *not* be representable in Humbug.

If you can get your head round that, just apply the same logic to events and the raise accessor.

Comment: thanks for answering my question again, though I am still struggling to understand this.  Perhaps I need to go away and look at it tomorrow.  I am viewing the Page class code in VB.NET using Reflector.  There are custom events in there without a RAISE EVENT between Custom Event and End Event.  The MSDN article I posted in the question says there should be a RAISE EVENT between custom event and end event.  Why is there no RAISE EVENT?

Comment: @w0051977: I don't know how I can say it any more clearly: **The MSDN article is talking about VB. RaiseEvent is only required in VB. It's language-specific.**

Comment: this question is about VB.NET.  I realise from what you have said that RAISE EVENT is apparently not required for C#.  I am asking a VB.NET question.  I have opened the Page class using Reflector and the code appears in VB.NET.  There is no RAISE EVENT for InitComplete and the other events.  Thanks again for continuing to help.  I was looking at one of your books on your website earlier.

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, there's no `RaiseEvent`... from which we can deduce that `Page` was not written in VB. VB is able to *use* classes which don't follow its own rules - there's nothing particularly strange about that.

Comment: @w0051977: Just noticed that I wrote C# in my first sentence in the answer instead of VB. Fixed now.